# Use wildcard to exclude paths in PVS-Studio configuration file

Tags: pvs-studio

I would like to exclude 3rd-party libraries from analysis.

```
exclude-path=*/boost/*
exclude-path=*/llvm/*
```

But it doesn't work. I still have Boost-related messages in output log.

How to filter out messages based on wildcard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As at the 2020 year, PVS-Studio supports exclusion of directories using masks both in the configuration file:

```
exclude-path=*/boost/*
exclude-path=*/llvm/*
```

and in the launch parameters:

```
pvs-studio-analyzer analyzer ... -e \*/boost/\* -e \*/llvm/\* ...
```